# Systemd not finding linked service after reboot (22.04)

Tags: 22.04, systemd, services

A service file resides at `/home/user/workspace/xyz.service`. Using `systemctl enable` with the absolute path puts a link in `/etc/systemd/system/` so I can run it as `service xyz restart`. However, I am unable to use the service after rebooting ("Unit xyz.service not found"). The link is still there in `/etc/systemd/system/`, and running `systemctl daemon-reload` lets me use the service again.

Similar behavior can be caused when the service file is located on a partition not available during systemd startup. I have ZFS encryption so maybe that is interfering? It is the standard setup (per the Ubuntu installer) so `/etc` and `/home` should be decrypted together on the rpool. Any ideas?

Comment: Happened to me as well. My home directory is in an encrypted drive that needs decryption, which means a late mount. I'd also like to know what really happens here.

Comment: I think this explains it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494647/105126

Comment: Thanks Majal. I was hoping for something more elegant but that will do it.